# Nested script in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Okay someone could really help me with this I've been working REALLY hard to get this working up until this point. One last thing is I need is the nextquestion1 function to bring me to the last from of my application.

I click on my button `nextQuestion_btn` to take me to one of the labled frames I have. I click on it and nothing happens. Also there is a lot of missing code in between the two Event Listener's , just so you know.

So...How can I make this code so I can trigger the next frame with the button?

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, checkTotal1000)

    function checkTotal1000(e:Event){

    var tech:Number = parseInt(tech_txt.text);
    var med:Number = parseInt(med_txt.text);
    var space:Number = parseInt(space_txt.text);
    var genetic:Number = parseInt(ge_txt.text);
    var worldComp:Number = parseInt(worldComp_txt.text);
    var mars:Number = parseInt(mars_txt.text);
    var worldColab:Number = parseInt(worldColab_txt.text);
    var nothing:Number = parseInt(nothing_txt.text);

    var zombieApocFinal:Number = zombieApoc + genetic;
    var robotApocFinal:Number =  robotApoc+ tech;
    var plagueFinal:Number = plague + med;
    var asteroidFinal:Number = asteroid + mars;
    var iceAgeFinal:Number = iceAge + nothing;
    var aliensFinal:Number = aliens + space;
    var nukeWarFinal:Number = nukeWar + worldComp;
    //var happyEverAfterFinal:Number = ;

trace(aliensFinal);

var total1000:Number = tech + med + space + 
    worldComp + mars + genetic + worldColab + nothing;


nextQuestion_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, nextQuestion1)
function nextQuestion1(e:MouseEvent){   

if(tech && med && space &&  genetic && worldComp 
   && mars && worldColab && nothing == 125){
    gotoAndStop(7);   
}
if(robotApocFinal > zombieApocFinal && plagueFinal &&
   asteroidFinal && iceAgeFinal && aliensFinal &&
   nukeWarFinal){
       gotoAndStop("Robot");  
}
else if(zombieApocFinal > robotApocFinal && plagueFinal &&
   asteroidFinal && iceAgeFinal && aliensFinal &&
   nukeWarFinal){
       gotoAndStop("Zombie");   
}
else if( plagueFinal > zombieApocFinal && robotApocFinal &&
   asteroidFinal && iceAgeFinal && aliensFinal &&
   nukeWarFinal){
       gotoAndStop("Plague");  
}

else if( asteroidFinal > zombieApocFinal && robotApocFinal && 
   plagueFinal && iceAgeFinal && aliensFinal &&
   nukeWarFinal){
       gotoAndStop("Asteroid");  
}
else if( iceAgeFinal > zombieApocFinal && robotApocFinal && 
   plagueFinal && asteroidFinal && aliensFinal &&
   nukeWarFinal){
       gotoAndStop("IceAge");  
}
else if( aliensFinal > zombieApocFinal && robotApocFinal && 
   plagueFinal && asteroidFinal && iceAgeFinal &&
   nukeWarFinal){
       gotoAndStop("Aliens");  
}
else if( nukeWarFinal > zombieApocFinal && robotApocFinal && 
   plagueFinal && asteroidFinal && iceAgeFinal &&
    aliensFinal){
       gotoAndStop("Nuke");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using binary flags, but you use `&&` operator which only works with booleans. This way if either of your ints is 0, no condition is satisfied. You apparently want to trigger the `gotoAndStop()` if one of the ints is greater than others. For this you can use the following code:

```
var bestFinal:int=Math.max(asteroidFinal, zombieApocFinal, robotApocFinal,
plagueFinal, iceAgeFinal, aliensFinal, nukeWarFinal);
if (bestFinal==asteroidFinal) {...}
else if (bestFinal==zombieApocFinal) {...}
...
```

If you are about to test if one var is greater than all the others, you cannot use what you've written, instead you use either `Math.max()` and check for equality, or you write many comparations and unite them via `&&`, like this:

```
if ((asteroidFinal > zombieApocFinal) && (asteroidFinal > robotApocFinal) && 
(asteroidFinal > plagueFinal) && (asteroidFinal > iceAgeFinal) && 
(asteroidFinal > aliensFinal) && (asteroidFinal > nukeWarFinal))
```